# how to write javascript value in translate3d css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write my javascript value to translate a CSS class, however it is not working as I want. Can anyone tell me why?

```js
var contentHeight = $('#mainContentHeight')[0].scrollHeight;
$('#menu').css({
  transform: "translateY(' + contentHeight + 'px)"
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you have mismatched quotes; `"` as the outer delimiters and `'` around where you concatenate the variable. Try this:

```
var contentHeight = $('#mainContentHeight')[0].scrollHeight;
$('#menu').css({
  transform: 'translateY(' + contentHeight + 'px)'
})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help.